# how to create an action controller helper class and how to access that in controller action?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, helper

Hi all a newbie question.

I am creating one rails application where after showing result to user i need to perform some other operations in background to update database.

(sorry i am poor at explaining things, see my example code for situation)

In my controller's action i am using third-party api to fetch data from remote server.
After showing fetched data to user i want to update database table with customized data on fetched data.

```
class MyController < ApplicationController
 def SomeAction
  #some logic
  @result = FetchDataFromApi#Using third party api to fetch huge data 
  #show result to user
  #after showing i need to do following operations elsewhere (controller helper)
  #based on some fetched result i want to update my table
  myId = @result.id
  dataObj = MyModel.find(myId)
  info = @result.information.gsub(',',' ') #some string operation
  dataObj.update_attributes(:info, info)
 end
end
```

I can use `spawnling` gem to perform extra operation after showing result to user. But i am just curious if i could do this with helper or other rails stuff.

Comment: If you need to run anything in a background you need to use sidekiq or similar tool.

Comment: @BroiSatse is there any side effects with actioncontroller helper?

Comment: ActionCOntroller helpers are a bridge between controller and a view unless you have sth else in mind. The response is always sent as a last step of the request life cycle, so any non-background code will need to finish execution before the response is send. You can try using threads, but those prove to cause more problems. Sidekiq is the solution I used in all my projects and it seems to do its stuff right.

Comment: sure i will, how about spawnling.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While there are cases where it makes sense to use a background processing. This is not one of them.

I assume 'show result to user' means rendering some template based on the data fetched from the api.

Actually, it might be a good idea to move accessing the external API into background, but that would require changing the flow. As for the updating the db record, its generally not a good idea to move it to background.

that being said, I wouldn't do the update in the controller, I'd move it into the model or a 'mutation' class:

```
class Model
  def self.update_from_api
    res = API.fetch ...
    object = find res.id
    object.update_from_api! res
    res
  end

  def update_from_api(api_data)
    update_attributes! info: api_data.gsub(....)
  end
end
```

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. I will try your suggestion and let you know.